# Logging different level for a specific class using logback?

Tags: debugging, logging, logback

Can I override a logging level for a specific class only using logback.xml? i.e everything remains in INFO, except for one class which will log in  DEBUG.

I appended this after the default one, but does not seem to work

```
<logger name="com.pack1.pack2.paack3.ClassName" additivity="false" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="file1"/>
</logger>
```

Thanks,
Donald

Comment: Have you tried the simpler statement `<logger name="com.pack1.pack2.paack3.ClassName" level="debug" />`?
AFAIK, the level isn't case-sensitive.
Can you share your full logback.xml?

Answer (score 9):

Doing it exactly like this works for me:

```
<logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="WARN" />
```

Comment: Careful with the appender-ref tag, for me this duplicated the log output. Simply using <logger name="com.pack1.pack2.paack3.ClassName" level="debug"/> after the root logger definition did it for me

Comment: It seems to work fine, thanks. It's nice that it's possible to either specify a specific class, a specific package or a parent package.

Answer (score 5):

(In case you set the name of logger explicitly) check if the name of the logger matches the name you set for your logger in your source code.

Use the upper case letters for level keywords (DEBUG, INFO ....)
and I am not sure but maybe you should use Level instead of level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've done that before and it's worked.  Try uppercase DEBUG.